# Efficient way to get line number of bunch of string from a file

Tags: java, file, io

I want to search a list of strings from the file and get the line number. I am looking for an efficient way to do it. I don't want to search one string at a time and open and close file.

Comment: Read the file into a `String[]`, where each row is a line. Then you only need to search that `String[]` - the line number would then be whatever index you are on when you find your search term(s).

Comment: Use a [LineNumberReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/LineNumberReader.html), and for each line read, see if any of your strings appear in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the line numbers where each String appears in the file using a `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>`.

This will allow you to find all lines in which a given String appears in a few microseconds.

Here's one way, if each line is one String:

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> index = new HashMap<>();
    LineNumberReader lines = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
    for (String line = lines.readLine(); line != null; line = lines.readLine()){
        index.computeIfAbsent(line, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(lines.getLineNumber());
    }
```

If each line is multiple Strings, change this line

```
index.computeIfAbsent(line, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(lines.getLineNumber());
```

to

```
Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).forEach(word ->
   index.computeIfAbsent(word, x -> new ArrayList<>())
       .add(lines.getLineNumber())
);
```

Comment: incase of duplicate string content map key value will be override